# php array, splitting 1 array in to 2 variables

Tags: php

I have an array that is used to get a persons name and i have the variable below which will give me the Full name name the user. e.g. John Smith. How do i split this array in to two variables.

e.g. $fb_firstname and $fb_lastname?

```
$fb_name = $user_profile['name'];
```

Comment: All the answers below are good when the pattern is {FName LName} and no middle initials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = explode(' ', $fb_name);
$fb_firstname = $arr[0];
$fb_lastname = $arr[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

use the explode function. and then assign output array [0] element as $fb_firstname and [1] element as $fb_lastname.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`explode`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/explode) for that and a space as delimiter:

```
$fb_name = $user_profile['name'];
list($fb_firstname, $fb_lastname) = explode(' ', $fb_name, 2) + array('', '');
```

The important part with that code is that the name needs to have one space only between first and last name and that the firstname comes first.

If there is no lastname, `$fb_lastname` will be an empty string.